# Manage Symfony App Heroku

Tags: symfony, heroku, production, staging, cleardb

I've a Symfony app on Heroku with ClearDb addons. I need to manage the app for test and prod. So I need two database: one for test and one for the production(principle);

I tryed the Heroku Pipeline, but when I promote the app from `staging` to `production`, the production app is connetted to staging db. How can solve ?
How you manage it?

**EDIT**
I discovered the mistake. I set the parameters via

```
$db = parse_url(getenv('CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL'));
$container->setParameter('database_host', $db['host']);
```

From a quick search for $container->setParameter I can see that this is a Symfony feature to interpolate values into code, however they mention the following warning in their docs:

> NOTE: You can only set a parameter before the container is compiled:
>   not at run-time. To learn more about compiling the container see
>   Compiling the Container.
>   https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html#getting-and-setting-container-parameters-in-php

Heroku handle only symfony apps in prod env. So the stage app also have the environment var as "prod". How can I set parameters for different env? Or dynamically?

Thanks,
AlterB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved with the Environment Variables.

I changed into app/config/config.yml this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
```

with that

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        url: '%env(CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL)%'
```

The app gets the db connection directly from Heroku Env. And it's done!